# left join en jpa sin multiples consultas

Tags: hibernate, jpa, java-8, jpql

Tengo dos tablas en la base de datos una PAISES y la otra de CIUDADES, tienen una relación de UNO a MUCHOS, un país tiene muchas ciudades. Requiero una consulta que me obtenga todos los paises con sus ciudades pero si el país no tienen ciudades asociadas tambien deberia estar en la respuesta de la consulta. Estoy haciendo la siguiente consulta

```
select distinct p FROM Pais p LEFT JOIN p.ciudades c
```

Esta consulta cumple con el objetivo, sin embargo cuando observo el log encuentro que se hacen `n + 1` consultas de acuerdo al número de paises existentes. Para evitar las multiples consultas hago un `fetch join`

```
select distinct p FROM Pais p JOIN FETCH p.ciudades
```

Con esta sentencia al mirar el log solo se ve una consulta realizada, esto reduce en `n` el número de consultas realizadas con respecto a la sentencia anterior, pero no me trae los paises que no tienen ciudades asociadas.

Como puedo traer los paises que no tienen ciudades asociadas pero de forma que solo se haga una consulta y no `n +1` consultas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En JPA las JOIN por defecto siempre son INNER JOIN.
En el primer caso has declarado una LEFT JOIN, pero en el segundo caso no.

Si añades LEFT a tu segunda consulta

```
select distinct p FROM Pais p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.ciudades
```

deberías obtener todos los países, tengan ciudades o no.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no soy muy experto en este tema pense que al usar el FETCH no se podia usar el LEFT o los otros tipos de JOIN.